# Java - Hibernate connection with Oracle

Tags: java, hibernate

I am connecting to remote Oracle db from AWS server using Java Hibernate connection, while the fetch is on if their is any network fluctuation, query hangs.

Below is the log of query:

> 23 Sep 2018 10:46:01   LiveSync INFO  {Query----->Select count(rec_no)
>   as count_rec from TBL_NAME where  REC_NO='XXXX'Booking Id--->XXXXX} 23
>   Sep 2018 11:02:09   LiveSync INFO  {SQL Error...could not execute
>   query}

In the first line, Query was fired at 10:46:01  to provide count of record, however due to network packet loss during that time, the response came to Java at 11:02:09, almost after 15 min.

Can anyone help me to immediately respond to Java on the network breakage?

Comment: Check if the security group allows for inbound connections to eh Oracle Db at the correct port